# I don't fully understand the sql statement

Tags: sqlite

I understand

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 1;
```

But I don't fully understand

```
SELECT * FROM T MyT WHERE MyT.C1 = 1;
```

What is MyT?

Comment: the part with "FROM T MyT" names the T table: MyT. This is useful when you want to do multiple selections from the same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyT is an alias for that reference of the table.

```
SELECT * FROM T MyT WHERE MyT.C1 = 1;
```

will work as well as

```
SELECT * FROM T MyT WHERE C1 = 1;
```

which will work as well as

```
SELECT MyT.FieldName FROM T MyT WHERE MyT.C1 = 1;
```

But this won't work:

```
 SELECT T.FieldName FROM T MyT WHERE MyT.C1 = 1;
```

You must use the alias to refer to the table after it is assigned.

These are essential when joining a table to itself:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
   T MyT INNER JOIN
   T MyT2
     ON MyT.ManagerID = MyT2.EmployeeID
 WHERE MyT.C1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

`MyT` is an alias. It's just a in-query rename. Helpful if the table name is very long or if you join to the same table again.

Comment: *essential* if you join to the same entity more than once.

Answer (score 1):

`MyT` is an alias for the `Table` `T`.  You after placing a name after, you can reference the `table` by the name.

Answer (score 1):

MyT is an alias of the table T which can be used to reference it.